# React setInterval is re-initialized to often

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I've a hard time understanding how `setInterval` works. My main problem is that an interval is re-initialized too often.
Basically, I want a context-sensitive sidebar to be modfied by `MainElement`, and I want this sidebar to do something at a regular base. In the real scenario there the timer gets cancelled when unmounting ofc.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// This is the component called from outside
export const MainLayout = () => {
  const [element2Content, setElement2Content] = useState<string | null>(null);
  return (
    <>
      <MainElement setElement2Content={setElement2Content}>
        Element1
      </MainElement>
      {element2Content && <Sidebar content={element2Content} />}
    </>
  );
};

// This component manipulates the sidebar via useEffect
const MainElement: React.FC<{ setElement2Content: (input: string) => void }> =
  ({ setElement2Content, children }) => {
    useEffect(() => setElement2Content('content set from element 1'), []);
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  };

// This component utilizes the setInterval, but doesn't work as expected
const Sidebar: React.FC<{ content: string }> = ({ content }) => {
  const [calls, setCalls] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log('interval called for', calls + 1, 'times');
      setCalls(calls + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return <div>{`content${content}, calls: ${calls}`}</div>;
};
```

The log is just `interval called for 1 times` in a loop.
In the browser I see the components rendered, and I see `interval called for 0 times` being changed to `interval called for 1 times`, where it stops.

So I'm wondering: Why does it stop at `1`? It seems like `setInterval` gets reset all the time.

To understand the behavior of a timer a bit more, I changed my `MainElement` to

```js
const MainElement: React.FC<{ setElement2Content: (input: string) => void }> =
  ({ setElement2Content, children }) => {
    useEffect(() => setElement2Content('content set in element 1'), []);
    useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log('interval called from mainelement');
      }, 1000);
    }, []);
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  };
```

Now, for some reason the `MainElement` is also re-rendered repeatedly, and so is the sidebar. The console logs

```
interval called in mainelement
interval called for 1 times
```

I'ld be grateful for any ideas or explanations!

Comment: There's no way for your set interval to ever be stopped...

Comment: @KevinB You're right, but that's why I wrote "In the real scenario there the timer gets cancelled when unmounting ofc." ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval is running correctly, but in your interval function `calls` is never being updated passed 1.  This is because the `calls` variable in the `setInterval` function is stale (i.e. it is always equal to 0 when the function is invoked, so `setCalls(call + 1)` will always update `calls` to 1.)  This staleness is because the `calls` variable in the function is captured in the closure formed when the effect is run during the first render of the component and never updated thereafter.

A quick way to address this is to use the functional version of the setState call:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log('interval called for', calls + 1, 'times');
      setCalls(prevCalls => prevCalls + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, the closure screws things up. I didn't realize and also didn't even know about the functional version of `setState`. Thanks!